# Cannot Resolve Repository Metadata for Customers

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to connect mongodDB with spring boot backend. I've made a small collection by the name of **customer** in local mongo database. I've already implemented the model, repository class and REST controller which contains end points for GET, POST and DELETE for customer.

Whenever I start the project and try to hit the end point, I get the following error:

[image: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve repository metadata for customers]

Below is the code that I've written:

**Customer.java (model class)**

```
package fashion.connect.models;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection= "customers")
public class Customers {

    @Id
    public ObjectId _id;
    public  String firstname;
    public String lastname;

    public Customers() {}

    public Customers(ObjectId _id, String firstname, String lastname) {
        this._id = _id;
        this.firstname= firstname;
        this.lastname= lastname;
    }

    public String get_id() {
        return _id.toHexString();
    }
    public void set_id(ObjectId _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}
```

**CustomerRepository.java**

```
package fashion.connect.repositories;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import fashion.connect.models.Customers;

@Repository
public interface CustomersRepository extends MongoRepository<Customers, String> {
    Customers findBy_id(ObjectId _id);
}
```

**CustomerController.java**

```
package fashion.connect.controllers;

import fashion.connect.models.Customers;
import fashion.connect.repositories.CustomersRepository;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomersController {
      @Autowired
      private CustomersRepository repository;

      @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public List<Customers> getAllCusomers() {
        return repository.findAll();
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public Customers getCustomertById(@PathVariable("id") ObjectId id) {
        return repository.findBy_id(id);
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
      public void modifyCustomerById(@PathVariable("id") ObjectId id, @Valid @RequestBody Customers customers) {
          customers.set_id(id);
          repository.save(customers);
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public Customers createCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody Customers customers) {
        customers.set_id(ObjectId.get());
        repository.save(customers);
        return customers;
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
      public void deleteCustomert(@PathVariable ObjectId id) {
        repository.delete(repository.findBy_id(id));
      }
```

[image: GET api response]

Here's the stack trace:

[image: Stack Trace]

Comment: Please add stacktrace to the question.

Comment: Post the error trace you get!

Comment: images are uploaded

Answer (score 0):

I think the add mongo repositories have to be added to the spring context as with annotation @EnableMongoRepositories:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/config/EnableMongoRepositories.html

And then you enter the package of all your mongo repos as base package:

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "repo.packages")
```

Comment: The tutorial which I've followed doesn't mention this point. Let me try

Comment: response remains the same even after adding this annotation ("message": "Could not resolve repository metadata for customers.")